# RuntimeError: new_Decoder returned -1 PocketSphinx español

Tags: python

Hola tengo un problema al intentar reconocimiento de voz con PocketSphinx.
mi código es el siguiente:

```
import os
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech, get_model_path

model_path = get_model_path()
print(model_path)

speech = LiveSpeech(
    verbose=False,
    sampling_rate=16000,
    buffer_size=2048,
    no_search=False,
    full_utt=False,
    hmm= os.path.join(model_path, 'es-es'),
    lm= os.path.join(model_path, 'es-20k.lm.bin'),
    dict= os.path.join(model_path, 'es.dict')
)

for phrase in speech:
    print(phrase)
```

Tambien intente hacer reconocimiento de voz con la libreria speech_recognition y la api de pocketsphinx, agregando diccionario, pero obtuve el mismo error.

```
"/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pocketsphinx/__init__.py", line 90, in 
__init__
super(Pocketsphinx, self).__init__(config)
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pocketsphinx/pocketsphinx.py", line 
273, in __init__
this = _pocketsphinx.new_Decoder(*args)
RuntimeError: new_Decoder returned -1
```

Gracias.

Comment: Parece que no encuentra el decoficador. Asegúrate que tienes instaladas las librerías Sphinxbase y Pocketsphinx.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta, intentare con volver a instalar esas librerías.

Comment: Hola durante la instalación de estas librerías he notado que se instalan en python 2.7.. sudo apt install autoconf libtool automake bison python-dev swig libpulse-dev 

mkdir sphinx
cd sphinx
git clone https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinxbase
git clone https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx                                          cd sphinxbase
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install                                                                              cd ../pocketsphinx
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install ¿Sabes como puedo descargarlo en python3?

Comment: Es complicado compilar estos módulos a partir de los fuentes si no tienes soltura con las herramientas que usan. Te recomiendo que instales pocketsphinx con pip3.